# Invalid argument for read-write mmap?

Tags: c, linux, virtualbox, mmap

I'm getting `-EINVAL` for some reason, and it's not clear to me why. Here's where I open and attempt to `mmap` the file:

```
if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR)) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}

struct stat statbuf;
if (fstat(fd, &statbuf))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "stat filed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}

char* fbase = mmap(NULL, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (fbase == MAP_FAILED)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT: I should add, the error is occurring in the `mmap`.

Comment: What do you mean? This is a snippet from something I'm writing.

Comment: The question is "where" in which line of your code snippet the EINVAL occurrs.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify. The error is in the mmap.

Comment: What is the value of `st_size`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

<strike>Turns out changing the `MAP_SHARED` to `MAP_PRIVATE` allows this to succeed.</strike>

This reason this was failing is subtle: My code is running inside a VirtualBox VM, and the file I was attempting to `mmap` was in a shared directory on my host machine. The VirtualBox virtual filesystem apparently doesn't implement `mmap` with the `MAP_SHARED` option across the boundary of the hypervisor.

If you'll read jxh's helpful comments on both my question and on his answer, it turns out that this code was working for him because he was likely attempting to `mmap` a host filesystem file into the host memory.

My observation that switching from `MAP_SHARED` to `MAP_PRIVATE` is also consistent with this: since privately mapped memory is invisible to other processes, the virtual filesystem driver will probably have no objection to mapping the memory.

The solution was to move the file I wanted to map into the guest's hard drive and perform manipulation from there.

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow.

Comment: Please don't think switching from `MAP_SHARED` to `MAP_PRIVATE` is an actual solution.  This isn't even a workaround.  Programs that use `MAP_SHARED` to modify the output file in-place will silently fail when using `MAP_PRIVATE`.  It may look like it's working, but it is probably not.

Answer (score 16):

Your `statbuf.st_size` is `0`. [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) will fail if the *length* parameter is `0`.

There are 3 listed reasons for `EINVAL` error `mmap()`:

> ```
> void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
>            int fd, off_t offset);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> - We don't like `addr`, `length`, or `offset` (e.g., they are too large, or not aligned on a page boundary).
> - (since Linux 2.6.12) `length` was 0.
> - `flags` contained neither `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED`, or contained both of these values.

Comment: I feel like a moron, but: it was zero, I've replaced the empty file, and it turns out the issue persists.

Comment: While the length was zero previously, I ensured that the file was nonempty, and the issue is still present. This question is a mess, I'll open a new one with more detail.

Comment: I must be losing my mind. I tried it inside a clean file and it worked, then I tried pasting the exact same code into the file it came from that it failed.

Comment: It turns out that setting `MAP_PRIVATE` instead of `MAP_SHARED` was enough to make it work.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything, because you said the code worked as it was in a clean file.

Comment: Aha! I finally figured it out! See my updated answer for details, but the long and the short of it that I was attempting to `mmap` a file that lived on my host machine from a VM.

Answer (score 0):

edit grub to add `iomem=relaxed` and reboot, make sure `cat /proc/cmdline` shows entry for `iomem=relaxed` after boot, re-run your program and check

```
[root@fedora ~]# cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-5.18.19-200.fc36.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora_fedora/root iomem=relaxed rhgb quiet
```