# Android 7.0 Build Error

Tags: android

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 by vagrant. However, when I run make Android 7.0, the following error happens.

Is there any suggestion or advise for me?

```
ninja: Entering directory `.'
[  0% 39/34804] host Java: ahat  (out/ho...A_LIBRARIES/ahat_intermediates/classes
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[  0% 53/34804] Generating TOC: out/tar.../core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.to
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(out/host/linux-x86/bin/ijar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp ) && (if cmp -s out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.toc ; then rm out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp ; else mv out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.toc ; fi )"
output_length=16459012
Unable to open output file out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp: Invalid argument
/bin/bash: line 1: 13460 Aborted                 (core dumped) ( out/host/linux-x86/bin/ijar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp )
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is as same as [Invalid argument for read-write mmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420473/invalid-argument-for-read-write-mmap?answertab=active#tab-top)

If you must be use share folder,please modify 
build/tools/ijar/zip.cc

```
@@ -994,7 +994,7 @@ ZipBuilder* ZipBuilder::Create(const char* zip_file, u8 estimated_size) {
    (u8) std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())
    void *zipdata_out = mmap(NULL, mmap_length, PROT_WRITE,
-                           MAP_SHARED, fd_out, 0);
+                           MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd_out, 0);
    if (zipdata_out == MAP_FAILED) {
      fprintf(stderr, "output_length=%llu\n", estimated_size);
      return NULL;
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/qXsk-YpMdYo maybe as same as you.

I hope it is useful.

Comment: the format is err.please modify code in ZipBuilder::Create() method: MAP_SHARED ->  MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14077868)

Comment: Thanks Jignesh Ansodariya.The essential part is ijar exe use mmap in build/tools/ijar/zip.cc.While you build AndroidN on VM,if the folder is in share folder,there would be an error about mmap.You can fix code : mmap(xxx,xxx,MAP_SHARED,xxx) to mmap(xxx,xxx,MAP_SHARED |MAP_ANONYMOUS,xxx) in ZipBuilder::Create() method,I think it will be ok, or else you need move code to no-share folder .Sorry,my english is poor.